# Element implicitly has an 'any' type although key is explicitly checked

Tags: typescript

I am explicitly checking wether a value is a valid key for the given object but still Typescript (4.7.4 and below) shows an error:

```
const errorColors = {
  "warning": "orange",
  "error": "red"
} as const;

function getLogColor(logType: "info" | "error" | "warning") {
  return logType in errorColors ? errorColors[logType] : "white"
}
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"info" | "error" | "warning"' can't be used to index type '{ readonly warning: "orange"; readonly error: "red"; }'.
> Property 'info' does not exist on type '{ readonly warning: "orange"; readonly error: "red"; }'.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgJwSBBhEAbFEYF4YDeAsAFAwwBEA7gIYJgCWYA5hQFyUo0twUA0pchUTIE7SgjgATCqQC+MGjlCQoAblKkAZgFcwwKA3AxmcKABkQzdFgQAKLMwAqATwAOcDhSZaQFGAA+lCIo-kHUdIwsFACUhIIwklA69DCOrh4wTPBIKDbYMAD8OaL5CBAA2unucAC6MF5UABYMULzyQA)

Can this code be adjusted to be type-safe without `// @ts-ignore`, `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors: true` or `as unknown as`?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open bug about this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284).

For the moment I would write it like this to fix the narrowing :

```
function getLogColor(logType: "info" | "error" | "warning") {
    return logType === 'error' || logType === 'warning' ? errorColors[logType] : "white"
}
```